# Replacing numeric values in Excel sheet with text values from other sheet

Tags: excel, surveymonkey

I am using Surveymonkey for a questionnaire. Most of my data has a regular scale from 0-6, and additionally an "Other" option that people can use in case they choose to not answer the item. However, when I download the data, Surveymonkey automatically assigns a value of 0 to that not-answer category, and it appears this cant be changed.

This leads to me not knowing when a zero in my numeric dataset actually means zero or just participants choosing to not answer the question. I can only figure that out by looking at another file that includes the labels of participants answers (all answers are provided by the corresponding labels, so this datafile misses all non-labeled answers...).

This leads me to my problem: I have two excel files of same size. I would need to find a way to find certain values in one dataset (text value, scattered randomly over dataset), and replace the corresponding numeric values in the other dataset (at the same position in the dataset) with those values.

I thought it would just be possible to find all values and copy paste in the same pattern, but I cannot seem to find a way to do that. I feel like I am missing an obvious solution, but after searching for quite a while I really could not find an answer to my specific question.

I have never worked with macros or more advanced excel programming before, but have a bit of knowledge about programming in itself. I hope I explained this well, I would be very thankful for any suggestions or scripts that could help me out here!

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I do not expect you to code for me, however since I dont have experience with VBA I wanted to make sure if this was a possible solution to the problem before diving into it. So far I mostly tried to find a way to highlight the position of the specific cells in the numeric sheet by mean so conditional formatting or copying, but both didnt work out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your Excel file is organised, but if it's like the legacy Condensed format, all you should need to do is to select the column corresponding to a given question (if that's what you have), and search and replace all 0 (match entire cell) with the text you want.